# Node JS: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `access_token` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, api, typeerror, server-side, zoom-sdk

I'm currently fetching a token from Zoom Api, which works fine. The problem lies after that when i'm trying to destructure the property so I can get the access_token.

```
 var username = "client id";
  var password = "client password";

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials',
  headers: {
    /**The credential below is a sample base64 encoded credential. Replace it with "Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(your_app_client_id + ':' + your_app_client_secret).toString('base64')"
    **/
   Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64'),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  };


const data = {
 "topic": "Demo Meeting",
             "type": 2,
             "start_time": "2020-05-05 12:00:00",
             "password": "Hey123",
             "agenda": "This is the meeting description",
             "settings": {
             "host_video": false,
             "participant_video": false,
             "join_before_host": false,
             "mute_upon_entry": true,
             "use_pmi": false,
             "approval_type": 0
             }
};



function getResponse() {
  return rp(options, function(error, response, body) {
   if (error) throw new Error(error)   

    const { access_token } = response.data;
    console.log(access_token)
    
  }).then(function (req) {
      //logic for your response
      console.log("inside response", req);
    
   return fetch("https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${req}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // API call failed...
        console.log('API call failed, reason ', err);
    });
}
```

When i'm runnin the code, I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `access_token` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `response.data` is `undefined`.

Put `console.log(response)` in your code and see what's there, and you'll see that the `data` property is missing.

Comment: Thanks that's indeed true. That was part of the problem. The other problem was that I didn't include; json: true in options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by doing this:

> Create a parameter named `AccessToken` and set it to `req.oidc.accessToken` create it before calling `const { token_type, access_token } = req.oidc.accessToken;`

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: "Express Demo",
    isAuthenticated: req.oidc.isAuthenticated(),
    user: req.oidc.user,
    accessToken: req.oidc.accessToken, // this part, when render create accessToken parameter
  })
})
```